# Java replaceFirst does not replace parenthesis

Tags: java, string

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String Str = new String("where test = (:viztest)");
      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(Str.replaceFirst("(:viztest)", "any('25','324')"));
   }
}
```

The result to this is

```
$javac Test.java
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M Test
Return Value :where test = (any('25','324'))
```

Where it should be `where test = any('25','324')`

Why does it ignore replacing the parenthesis and how it should be fixed?

Comment: Your first step should **always** be [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), which quite clearly says *"Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given **regular expression** with the given replacement."* So then you'd ask yourself if the paren issue might relate to that "regular expression" thing, and look at those...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need escape the parenthesis (the argument is a regex, `(...)` defines a capture group):

```
Str.replaceFirst("\\(:viztest\\)")
```

or

```
Str.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("(:viztest)")
```

Comment: with `\\(` as it is a regex escape

Comment: Thank you i tried before with \ slash but didn't work

Comment: `Pattern.quote("(:viztest)")` is the most reliable way to ensure everything that needs to be escaped is escaped, whilst leaving your original strings intact.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy: replaceFirst expects a regular expression as first parameter. In a regular expression, parentheses indicate a group. You need to escape them with backslashes.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the brackets in `[]` and it will remove those also:

```
System.out.println(Str.replaceFirst("[(]:viztest[)]", "any('25','324')"));
```